# Google Tag Manager enhanced ecommerce - Datalayers

Tags: magento-1, google-analytics, ecommerce-tracking, google-tag-manager

I have setup enhanced ecommerce for my client. (batteribyen.dk). They use Magento Enterprise

I followed this guide:

https://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/marketing/google-universal-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce.html

My problem is:

1. I don't get productinformation in Google Analytics.
2. I miss the steps (Add To Cart and Continued checkout in Analytics)

My datalayer in Google Tag Manager only works in productview and on purchase. Alle the other steps it dosen't create a datalayer and my AddToCart event isn't called at all.

Have anyone tried anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the same boat. I'm starting to think about using this extension which has a free plan: https://www.weltpixel.com/google-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce-tag-manager-magento-2.html

But I can't use a testing environment, so I'm on the fence here.

Answer (score 0):

We couldn't make Magento Enterprise out of the box solution work and there were quite a lot of events and data missing from GA so we ended up using the following extension which worked well for us.

https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-google-tag-manager-enhanced-ecommerce-tracking.html